# HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url

Tags: azure, entra-id

I'm trying to create an principal account from the azure shell (portal.azure.com browser), but seems that can't go through:

```
stan@Azure:~$ az ad sp create-for-rbac --sdk-auth > my.azureauth
Role assignment creation failed.

Error occurred in request., RetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/**********/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/d5786742-5a32-486f-a669-31807195e5fc?api-version=2018-01-01-preview (Caused by ResponseError('too many 504 error responses',))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 445, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 731, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 731, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 731, in urlopen
    body_pos=body_pos, **response_kw)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 711, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(method, url, response=response, _pool=self)
  File "/opt/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='management.azure.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /subscriptions/4******/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments/d5786742-5a32-486f-a669-31807195e5fc?api-version=2018-01-01-preview (Caused by ResponseError('too many 504 error responses',))
```

it seems that the root cause is:

```
too many 504 error responses
```

but the same command worked yesterday, and it's by the book, please advise.

Thank you in advance,
Stan

Comment: This is an outage. You can check the Azure Status page to monitor updates by the link:https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/.

Comment: Thank you Sunny, I've spotted on social medias that as well; maybe it's a good moment to consider a bit better (intuitive) error handling, those things can happen to everybody, at least we know now :).